# Emulator trace throws `BuiltinEvaluationFailure of UnIData` error with simple minting policy

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, minting, offchain

## Source

https://github.com/tomazvila/plutus_minting_test

## Problem

Running smart contract with simple minting use case fails to mint.

### Error

```
Slot 00001: *** CONTRACT STOPPED WITH ERROR: "\"WalletContractError (ValidationError (ScriptFailure (EvaluationError [] \\\"BuiltinEvaluationFailure of UnIData\\\")))\""
```

### Setup

```
cardano_node@demoserver:~/coreapp_testing/new_repo$ uname -a
Linux demoserver 5.4.0-100-generic #113-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 3 18:43:29 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
cardano_node@demoserver:~/coreapp_testing/new_repo$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 3.6.2.0
compiled using version 3.6.2.0 of the Cabal library
cardano_node@demoserver:~/coreapp_testing/new_repo$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.10.7
```

How to run

```
cardano run trace
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that Minting script is expecting Integer as a redeemer:

```
mkPolicy :: TxOutRef -> Integer -> ScriptContext -> Bool
mkPolicy utxo _ ctx = validate
```

And off-chain code with:

```
TxConstraints.mustMintValueWithRedeemer unitRedeemer val
```

call passes unitRedeemer. Validator tries to deconstruct unitRedeemer to Integer and throws an error.

Bonus: `Constraint.mustMintValue` passes unitRedeemer by default